# Find *.txt files in directory c++

Tags: c++, file, directory

I want to get txt files from directory with using c++. I searched in google and found "dirent.h" but I can't using this library. It gives me a C1083 fault. Here is my codes.I'm already included fstream,dirent.h vs...

```
ifstream fin;
string dir, filepath;
int num;
DIR *dp;
struct dirent *dirp;
struct stat filestat;

cout << "dir to get files of: " << flush;
getline(cin, dir);  

dp = opendir(dir.c_str());
if (dp == NULL)
{
    cout << "Error(" << errno << ") opening " << dir << endl;
    return errno;
}

while ((dirp = readdir(dp)))
{
    filepath = dir + "/" + dirp->d_name;


    if (stat(filepath.c_str(), &filestat)) continue;
    if (S_ISDIR(filestat.st_mode))         continue;


    fin.open(filepath.c_str());
    if (fin >> num)
        cout << filepath << ": " << num << endl;
    fin.close();
}
```

`

Comment: I don't know if you can use C++17, but if you can then you'll have access to the filesystem library in the standard library.

Comment: Have you tried looking up [C1083](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et4zwx34.aspx)? How are you including the corresponding headers?

Comment: Prior to C++17, there's  boost. Far easier than dirent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function are you are using are from POSIX standard and are not implemented on Windows.

If you need portable C++ solution, the only way is to use C++17 [filesystem library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) - but it is not implemented in Visual Studio 2015 and earlier.

Another solution is to use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/), more precisely Boost.Filesystem library.

Both solutions do not handle wildcards, so you will have to implement filtering yourself, probably using `std::regex`.

You can also use native Windows API functions `FindFirstFile`, `FindNextFile`, `FindClose` - those support wildcards. MSDN has an [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx) on how to use those.

Answer (score 1):

what is about using boost ?
For instance (to be checked):

```
int     filter_txt_files (std::string offset,std::vector<std::string>& vec_res)
{  
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    boost::filesystem::path offset_path(offset);

    for (boost::filesystem::directory_iterator it (offset_path, ec), eit;
         it != eit;
         it.increment (ec)
         )
    {
        if (ec)
            continue;

        if (boost::filesystem::is_regular_file (it->path ()))            
        {
            if(it->path ().extension ().string () == "txt")
                vec_res.push_back(it->path ().string());
        }
        // if you need recursion
        else if (boost::filesystem::is_directory (it->path ()))
        {
            filter_txt_files(it->path ().string(),vec_res);
        }
    }
    return ((int)vec_res.size());
}
```